# chat message input wont get clear when you post chat message in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am unable to clear the input box when message is post.

For Ex. If I send message "hi" and click on Send button, it shows the chat message in chat window but input box remain as it is i.e message doesn't get clear.
Exactly, I don't know where I am getting wrong.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Here is script.js where addMessage() is called with 2 parameters.

script.js

```
$scope.addMessage = function(groupkey,message) {
$scope.messages = userobjectgroupnode($rootScope.authData.uid, groupkey);
$scope.message = " ";
};
```

showmessage.html

```
<form ng-submit="addMessage(groupkey,message);">
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your message here" ng-model="message">
<md-button type="submit" aria-label="menu">
    <md-icon class="material-icons">send</md-icon>
</md-button>
</form>
```

I have refer following link: http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/cWBQH/embedded/result%2Cjs%2Chtml/

Comment: I have tried to replicate this behavior, but it looks like it works fine.  I am suspecting it is possibly a browser issue - or possibly an intermittent async issue.  Maybe try tossing your addMessage code into a `$timeout`, or (not ideal) calling `$scope.$apply()` at the end?

Comment: @KennyThompson: Its not browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved:
Added controller to form. Since it was not getting specific controller.

```
<form ng-submit="addMessage(groupkey,message);" ng-controller="MyController">
```